# How to send loading data before sending a file in Express Get Request

Tags: javascript, express, ffmpeg, request, fluent-ffmpeg

I have an express Node.js server.

The objective of this server is make a process with ffmpeg and to send the file as result.

I manage to know the percentage of the process. But I don't know how to **make the client aware of** the percentage before it sends the file.

So here is my server-side code :
(I omitted some part of the ffmpeg process because, this is not very important, the important thing is to send the variable 'percent').

```c
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');

app.get('/download', (req,res) => {
    const video = new ffmpeg('myaudio.mp3');
    let total;
    video
        .format('mp3')
        .on('codecData', (data) => {
            total = parseInt(data.duration.replace(/:/g, ''));
        })
        .on('progress', (progress) => {
            const time = parseInt(progress.timemark.replace(/:/g, ''));
            const percent = (time / total) * 100;
            console.log(percent); // I want to send 'percent' to the client instead of console.log
        })
        .on('end', () => {
            res.status(200).sendFile(output); // then it sends the file to client
        })
        .save(output);
});
```

if you have a solution, can you show the client-side example, (axios or fetch) please ?

Comment: Web socket, long polling or constantly making requests from the client every second